# How to convert RAND_bytes() return value to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, aes

I need to create a random key to my Aes encryption to my project and need to store the key in my SqlLite db and when I need to the key I need to get it from db and convert to same type to use my decryption.

I'm using following code :

```
    unsigned char key_bytes[16];
    RAND_bytes(key_bytes, sizeof(key_bytes));
    string key = string((char *)key_bytes, sizeof(key_bytes));
    cout << key << endl;
```

and It returns me like :
ԌwH�eM��>�

I don't know how to store this return value in my db.I need to a string value.

Also my referance link is http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-openssl-aes-gcm-code-sample

Comment: It's not a string as you can see, just random bytes. You can store it as a BLOB type.

Answer (score -1):

You can't just convert bytes to String directly.
You should use conversion algorithm like base64, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.

Comment: I'm searching for "convert bytes to string in c++" in google but it returns me methods like `string((char *)key_bytes, sizeof(key_bytes));`.So it returns same string values.